# is iPhone autorelease working for c arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsautoreleasepool, static-array

will autorelease release my non-object c array?
I am wondering, because perhaps only objects know their reference count?
here's my code:

```
-(int *)getCombination{
    int xIndex = arc4random() % [self._num1 count] + 1;
    int yIndex = arc4random() % [self._num2 count] + 1;
    int *combination;
    combination[0] = [[self._num1 objectAtIndex:xIndex]intValue];
    combination[1] = [[self._num2 objectAtIndex:yIndex]intValue];
    return combination;
}
```

and this is my main() function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([YYAAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

So is the autorelease working for objects only or will it release my c array from getCombination?

Edit:
Since the answer is no, autorelease doesn't work for c arrays/pointers I used the following code which uses NSArrays instead:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Multiplication : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *_combinations;

-(id)initArrays;
-(NSArray *)getCombination;

@end

#import "Multiplication.h"

@implementation Multiplication
@synthesize _combinations;

-(void)initializeArray{
    self._combinations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
            NSNumber *y = [NSNumber numberWithInt:j];
            [self._combinations addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:([x intValue] * [y intValue])], nil]];
        }
    }
}

-(NSArray *)getCombination{
    if ([self._combinations count] == 0) {
        [self initializeArray];
    }

    int index = arc4random() % [self._combinations count];
    NSArray *arr = [self._combinations objectAtIndex:index];
    [self._combinations removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    return arr;
}

-(id)initArrays{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeArray];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

BTW this function is supposed to provide a method for randomly displaying every combination in the multiplication table of 10X10 and restart when all combinations have been displayed and equal number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autorelease` is a message that can be sent to Objective C objects. Before ARC, you needed to do it explicitly, like this:

```
MyObject *obj = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Under ARC, the compiler figures out the `autorelease` part for you, but the message is stil sent to the object; that object gets added to the autorelease pool as a result. When autorelease pool gets drained, all objects inside it are sent a `release` message. If there are no other references to the object, its reference count drops to zero, and the object get cleaned up.

C arrays do not respond to `autorelease` or `release` message: they are not Objective C entities, so they do not respond to messages at all. Therefore, you must deal with the memory that you allocate for these arrays manually, by calling `malloc`<sup>1</sup> and `free`.

Of course you can place autoreleased objects inside a C array, and these objects will be cleaned up in the regular course of action. For example

```
NSNumber **numbers = malloc(2, sizeof(NSNumber*));
numbers[0] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
numbers[1] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:456];
return numbers;
```

If the caller does not `retain` `NSNumber` objects inside the `numbers` array, these objects will be autoreleased<sup>2</sup>. The `numbers` object, however, needs to be cleaned up separately:

```
free(numbers);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You did not call `malloc` in your code, so accessing `combinatopn[...]` is undefined behavior.

<sup>2</sup> Causing hanging references in the process.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my questions. Thanks for all other replies also, but I really think the best for my here is to use an NSArray instead of relearning memory allocations... (never did learn c thoroughly). I'll post my new code for anyone who would like to see.

Comment: "but the message is stil sent to the object; that object gets added to the autorelease pool as a result" not necessarily

Answer (score 2):

Autorelease is for Objective-C objects.  Also, you aren't creating a C array, just a pointer variable.  Your assignments to `combination[n]` are writing to unallocated memory.

Comment: I happen to know what allocating memory is, but you shouldn't have assumed that. if I didn't know what it was, your answer could confuse me. No downvoting though.

Comment: If you didn't know about allocating memory, you would have looked it up.  Otherwise, you would have been someone who was not intended to be a programmer and your confusion would have been irrelevant.  :-)